Flutter's pub outdated command does not show all dependencies
In a Flutter Project, in pubspec.yaml, I have:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  provider: ^6.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2

But when I run dart pub outdated, it lists:
Package Name   Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies:
firebase_auth  *3.11.2  *3.11.2     5.1.3       5.1.3   
    
dev_dependencies:
flutter_lints  *3.0.2   *3.0.2      4.0.0       4.0.0 

Why doesn't it show provider in the outdated list?  On pub.dev it says the latest version is 6.1.2

Because provider is not in your pubspec.yaml file as a dependency, ( add provider to dependencies and try again )

It is right above firebase_auth in my question. I don't understand.
